# React Js success message on form submission

Tags: reactjs

I want that when I submit my form, I get a successfully submitted form message, but when I submit my form, it is directly submitted and no message comes. Sometimes, it doesn't submit the form, and it keeps showing the message `Please fill all the fields`.

Can someone tell me what to do or what I am doing wrong?

```
const Account2 = () => {
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState([]);
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    kookid: "",
    price: "",
    description: "",
  });
  const menuCollectionRef = collection(db, "menu");

  useEffect(() => {
    onSnapshot(menuCollectionRef, (snapshot) => {
      setMenu(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          return {
            id: doc.id,
            viewing: false,
            ...doc.data(),
          };
        })
      );
    });
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!form.kookid || !form.price || !form.description) {
      alert("Please fill out all fields");
      return alert("Form Submitted Successfully");
    }

    addDoc(menuCollectionRef, form);

    setForm({
      kookid: "",
      price: "",
      description: "",
    }).then(() => {});
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="form-group2">
        <label>Kook Id</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder=""
          value={form.kookid}
          onChange={(e) => setForm({ ...form, kookid: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group2">
        <label>Description</label>
        <textarea
          placeholder=""
          value={form.description}
          onChange={(e) => setForm({ ...form, description: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>

      <center>
        <div className="buttons2">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </center>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!form.kookid || !form.price || !form.description) {
   alert("Please fill out all fields")
   return alert("Form Submitted Successfully")
}
```

You have small trouble with the above code snippet. The condition is any form field is empty, you throw `alert("Please fill out all fields")` which is correct, but `alert("Form Submitted Successfully")` should not be a part of the above condition.

You can modify it to

```
if (!form.kookid || !form.price || !form.description) {
   alert("Please fill out all fields")
   return //to stop other logic, if any field is empty
   //return alert("Form Submitted Successfully")
}

alert("Form Submitted Successfully") //move the successful alert out of the above condition
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems obviously wrong:

```js
if (!form.kookid || !form.price || !form.description) {
  alert("Please fill out all fields");
  return alert("Form Submitted Successfully");
}
```

First you show an error message, and then immediately afterward you show a success message. Does that make sense to you?

Second, your form submit handler should `return false` in addition to preventing default. Do that in bad cases *and* good cases.

Bonus: this code seems pointless, and you should remove it:

```js
setForm({
  kookid: "",
  price: "",
  description: "",
}).then(() => {}); // <-- this .then accomplishes nothing
```